# Python script using json.load to compare two files and replace stringss

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a *JSON* file like this: `[{"ID": "12345", "Name":"John"}, {"ID":"45321", "Name":"Max"}...]` called `myclass.json`. I used `json.load` library to get "ID" and "Name" values.

I have another .txt file with the content below. File name is `list.txt`:

```
Student,12345,Age 14
Student,45321,Age 15
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to create a script in python that compares the two files line by line and replace the student ID for the students name in list.txt file, so the new file would be:

```
Student,John,Age 14
Student,Max,Age 15
.
.
```

Any ideas?

My code so far:

```
import json

with open('/myclass.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

for key in data:
  x = key['Name']
  z = key['ID']

with open('/myclass.json', 'r') as file1:
  with open('/list.txt', 'r+') as file2:
     for line in file2:   
       x = z
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import json
import csv


with open('myclass.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = list(reader)


def get_name(id_):
    for item in data:
        if item['ID'] == id_:
            return item["Name"]
            

with open('list.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        name = get_name(id_ = row[1])
        if name:
            row[1] = name
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Keep in mind that this script technically does not replace the items in the `list.txt` file one by one, but instead reads the entire file in and then overwrites the `list.txt` file entirely and constructs it from scratch. I suggest making a back up of `list.txt` or naming the new `txt` file something different incase the program crashes from some unexpected input.

Answer (score 0):

One option is individually open each file for each mode while appending a list for matched  ID values among those two files as

```
import json

with open('myclass.json','r') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

j=0
lis=[]
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        if data[j]['ID']==line.split(',')[1]:            
            s = line.replace(line.split(',')[1],data[j]['Name'])
            lis.append(s)
        j+=1

with open('list.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for i in lis:
        f_out.write(i)
```